# Get Latest Article in Two Combined Django Queryset That's Converted to a List

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to retrieve latest article that's added to my `Article` and `SharedArticle` model.

```
import itertools

articles = Article.objects.all()[:15]
shared = SharedArticle.objects.all()[:15]

all_articles = sorted(itertools.chain(articles, shared), 
                  key=lambda x: x.date_created, reverse=True)[-10:]
```

After combining these two query results I get the latest 10 out of the total 30 and the only thing the query results have in common is `date_created` column.

How I get the latest `articles` and `shared` from `all_articles`?

Comment: what is the default order of `Article` and `SharedArticle` ?

Comment: @sax: by date_created, in descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first Article:

```
next(obj for obj in all_articles if isinstance(obj, Article))
```

last Article

```
next(obj for obj in all_articles[::-1] if isinstance(obj, Article))
```

first SharedArticle:

```
next(obj for obj in all_articles if isinstance(obj, SharedArticle))
```

last SharedArticle

```
next(obj for obj in all_articles[::-1] if isinstance(obj, SharedArticle))
```

Comment: I already did `min([obj for obj in all_articles if isinstance(obj, Article)])` and `min([obj for obj in all_articles if isinstance(obj, SharedArticle)])`. Thank you.